# Keeping a logo centered but also fixed when browser resizes

Tags: html, css

How would i fix this logo to allways be in the center top of the page and doesn't move as browser changes size, so when the browser changes size the logo stays in its old position and will not recenter its self.

Here is my current CSS

CSS

```
#logo { 
position:absolute;
background-image:url(../img/LOGO1.png);
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
top:0px;
margin: 0 auto;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

Thankyou for your help

Comment: please provide jsfiddle

Comment: what do i add in the js fiddle ?

Comment: position:fixed; will do but some considerations should be considered :P please provide a fiddle... :)

Comment: put your html/css here:http://jsfiddle.net/ then save that and get a link

Comment: open jsfiddle.net... post your code.... save and share the link..

Comment: @user3241684 What about some relevant code related to this topic?

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
body
{
     height: 1000px;
}
#logo { 
position:absolute;
background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUYP4.jpg?s=128&g=1');
background-size:150px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
position: fixed;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:1;
top:0px;
margin: 0 auto;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="logo">
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCm87/2/)

Comment: This is what mine already does in Dreamweaver, i am trying to keep the image stuck so the it doesn't move at all, when the browsers size changes horizontally

Comment: How it will not move and you like that will be in the center?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your margin, left and right properties and add this one:

```
margin-left:100px;
```

This way, your image will always be 100px to the right.

```
#logo { 
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url(../img/LOGO1.png);
  background-size:150px;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  z-index:1;
  top:0px;
  margin-left:100px;
}
```